# fabric-ca-client cannot find ./utils.js

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I'm trying to test out the fabcar example from IBM (https://github.com/IBM/fabcar-blockchain-sample). This is something that I've done before on my computer and it worked. I have installed windows-build-tools and can see that Python 2.7 is installed. Npm install in web-app -> server give the following response:

```
$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

> pkcs11js@1.0.19 install C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\pkcs11js
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\pkcs11js>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  main.cpp
  dl.cpp
  const.cpp
  error.cpp
  v8_convert.cpp
  template.cpp
  mech.cpp
  param.cpp
  param_aes.cpp
  param_rsa.cpp
  param_ecdh.cpp
  pkcs11.cpp
  async.cpp
  node.cpp
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
     Creating library C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app 
  \server\node_modules\pkcs11js\build\Release\pkcs11.lib and object C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample- 
  master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\pkcs11js\build\Release\pkcs11.exp
  Generating code
  All 1243 functions were compiled because no usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found.
  Finished generating code
  pkcs11.vcxproj -> C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\s 
  erver\node_modules\pkcs11js\build\Release\\pkcs11.node
  pkcs11.vcxproj -> C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\s 
  erver\node_modules\pkcs11js\build\Release\pkcs11.pdb (Full PDB)

> grpc@1.23.3 install C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fabric-ca-client\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
[grpc] Success: "C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fabric-ca-client\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" is installed via remote

> grpc@1.23.3 install C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
[grpc] Success: "C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" is installed via remote

> grpc@1.23.3 install C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fabric-network\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
[grpc] Success: "C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fabric-network\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" is installed via remote

> grpc@1.24.2 install C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
[grpc] Success: "C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" is installed via remote

> nodemon@1.19.4 postinstall C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN server@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN server@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN server@1.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: abbrev@1.1.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.abbrev.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ansi-regex@2.1.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ansi-regex):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ansi-regex' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.ansi-regex.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: aproba@1.2.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aproba):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aproba' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.aproba.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: balanced-match@1.0.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\balanced-match):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\balanced-match' -> 
'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.balanced-match.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: chownr@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\chownr):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\chownr' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.chownr.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: code-point-at@1.1.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\code-point-at):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\code-point-at' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.code-point-at.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: concat-map@0.0.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\concat-map):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\concat-map' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.concat-map.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: console-control-strings@1.1.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\console-control-strings):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\console-control-strings' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.console-control-strings.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: core-util-is@1.0.2 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\core-util-is):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\core-util-is' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.core-util-is.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: deep-extend@0.6.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\deep-extend):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\deep-extend' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.deep-extend.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: delegates@1.0.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\delegates):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\delegates' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.delegates.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: detect-libc@1.0.3 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\detect-libc):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\detect-libc' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.detect-libc.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fs.realpath@1.0.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\fs.realpath):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\fs.realpath' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.fs.realpath.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: has-unicode@2.0.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\has-unicode):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\has-unicode' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.has-unicode.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: inherits@2.0.4 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\inherits):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\inherits' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.inherits.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ini@1.3.5 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ini):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ini' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.ini.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: isarray@1.0.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\isarray):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\isarray' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.isarray.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: minimist@0.0.8 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\minimist):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\minimist' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.minimist.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ms@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ms):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ms' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.ms.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: npm-normalize-package-bin@1.0.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\npm-normalize-package-bin):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\npm-normalize-package-bin' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.npm-normalize-package-bin.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: number-is-nan@1.0.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\number-is-nan):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\number-is-nan' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.number-is-nan.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: object-assign@4.1.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\object-assign):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\object-assign' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.object-assign.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: os-homedir@1.0.2 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\os-homedir):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\os-homedir' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.os-homedir.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: os-tmpdir@1.0.2 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\os-tmpdir):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\os-tmpdir' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.os-tmpdir.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: path-is-absolute@1.0.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\path-is-absolute):   
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\path-is-absolute' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.path-is-absolute.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: process-nextick-args@2.0.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\process-nextick-args):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\process-nextick-args' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.process-nextick-args.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: minimist@1.2.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\rc\node_modules\minimist):   
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\rc\node_modules\minimist' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\rc\node_modules\.minimist.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: safe-buffer@5.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\safe-buffer):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\safe-buffer' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.safe-buffer.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: safer-buffer@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\safer-buffer):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\safer-buffer' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.safer-buffer.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: sax@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\sax):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\sax' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.sax.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: semver@5.7.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\semver):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\semver' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.semver.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: set-blocking@2.0.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\set-blocking):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\set-blocking' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.set-blocking.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: signal-exit@3.0.2 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\signal-exit):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\signal-exit' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.signal-exit.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: strip-json-comments@2.0.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\strip-json-comments):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\strip-json-comments' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.strip-json-comments.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: util-deprecate@1.0.2 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\util-deprecate):       
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\util-deprecate' -> 
'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.util-deprecate.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: wrappy@1.0.2 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\wrappy):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\wrappy' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.wrappy.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: yallist@3.1.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\yallist):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\yallist' -> 'C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.yallist.DELETE'

added 790 packages from 373 contributors and audited 3892 packages in 182.878s

3 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

When I run node enrollAdmin.js (https://github.com/IBM/fabcar-blockchain-sample/tree/master/web-app/server) the following error message is displayed:

```
 node enrollAdmin.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './utils.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\emma.rasmusson\Downloads\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\fabcar-blockchain-sample-master\web-app\server\node_modules\fabric-ca-client\lib\FabricCAServices.js:10:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

The dependencies in package.json are the following:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "eslint": "^6.5.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "fabric-ca-client": "~1.4.0",
    "fabric-network": "~1.4.0",
    "grpc": "^1.24.2",
    "handlebars": "4.5.3",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "tar": ">=2.2.2"
  }
```

Node version: 10.17.0
Npm version: 6.13.7

Any thoughts on how I can fix this issue?

Thank you!

Update: Fabric-ca-client was updated to version 1.4.6 yesterday. Tested 1.4.5 and it works like a charm.. seems like there is a bug/fix in 1.4.6 or something in the release that result in failure on Windows PC (have tried two different now). Checking the change log for the release

Comment: I believe this issue is known and that a fix will be provided in a 1.4.7 release

Comment: FYI: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABN-1500

Comment: @david_k Thank you! I update node to 12 and tried the 1.4.7 release now. Works like charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David mentioned, the fix is in the 1.4.7 release. Tested it and it worked.